# Deselect button (Radio Button) Swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uibutton, switch-statement

I am trying to make 2 buttons in Swift behave like Radio Buttons.

Each button has a different image for when they are Selected and Not Selected.

When I click one button, I want the other Button to go back to being in the "Not Selected" state and showing the "Not Selected" image if it was previously selected.

I'm using a switch statement:

```
func toggle(sender: UIButton) {


    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


    case 2:
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


    default:
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }



    }
```

This statement works for changing the buttons, but allows for both to be selected at the same time. How do I make it so that the other button is de-selected when you click the other one of the buttons?

Comment: you can use the highlighted property just to show selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to create outlets for you buttons then every time the toggle func is fired set both to unselected and then set the sender selected.

```
func toggle(sender: UIButton) {
//Sender is already selected no need to do anything
if sender.isSelected {
    return
}

button1.isSelected = false
button2.isSelected = false
sender.isSelected = true
}
```